# Issue facing in using logger in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, logging

Actually in my web project i am using logger concept to save user operations. it is working but my where i am facing the problem is when a user-A is loggedin means it is saving properly his operations in database but at the same time when another user-B is logged in means it is overlaping the information by saving User-B with User-A Details in database. is there any solution. below is my sample code

```
            GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("PageViewed", "mInbox Page");
            GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("PageType", "Mob");
            GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("UserId", Session["UserID"].ToString());
            logger.Info("*** mInbox Page ***");
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Sir i updated my question with code